# How to burn multiple mp3 tracks to a series of plain audio CDs

Tags: mp3, burning, brasero

The default Brasero application, as far as I can tell, does nothing at all when asked to burn lots of mp3 tracks to more than one CDR. I know about the permission issues with some of its supporting applications (cdrdao etc), and fixing those does not overcome the fundamental problem I'm seeing that the "Burn Multiple Disks" option does precisely nothing at all.

Is that just a known problem (like the permissions problem with the underlying tools)? I realize that not too many people burn old-school audio CDs nowadays.

Sorry this is 16.04, I apologize for not clarifying.

Audio "projects" involving mp3 file groups that *do* fit on a single plain audio CD can be burned successfully with Brasero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This apparent feature of Brasero is not working for a long time. This [bug report on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/brasero/+bug/820709) was filed back in 2011 and filed as "Expired" in july 2018.

It may not be obvious to find graphical CD burning software that automatically creates multiple audio CD's from many audio files. With some scripting involving the appropriate command line tools, it is possible to achieve automated "mass burning" of many mp3 files to many audio CD's. Unless such a script already exists, you will have to make it yourself.

Comment: Yes, that works. However when I start an Audio project with more files than will fit on a single CD, the UI shows a blue banner at the top of the project view with a button that invites me to burn multiple discs. That's what does nothing, or at least nothing as far as I can tell.

Comment: You are right indeed. The option is there in Brasero, but apparently does not work, and never may have worked. I included reference to a bug report from 2011 in my corrected answer.